# How to read the stack trace file in Android?

Tags: android

I'm trying to print the logs in the screen. But it's showing an error that:

> Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt':Permission denied.

How can I access the stack trace file?

Comment: Can you plz tell how you are trying to this I mean show some code

Comment: you can move that text file to your desktop(or any location) and you can open it no?

Comment: public void ReadLogs() { try {                               Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d"); BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(               new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));          StringBuilder log=new StringBuilder();                        String line = bufferedReader.readLine();                       while (line != null) { log.append(line); } Log_Details_button.setText(log.toString()); }                  catch (IOException e) { } }

Comment: actually you dont have permission to that folder that's why in common practice this is not feasible unless you are root

Comment: okk..Then can u please help me out in how to get the logs and copy it to a new text file?

Comment: Select a log then press Ctrl+A then Ctrl+C and paste in txt file

Answer (score 1):

All the stack trace is printed in the **LogCat** so go to DDMS window and select the **LogCat** tab.

If log cat is not visible select the device Tab from the DDMS and select your device on which you are testing.

If both the Tabs aren't visible to you then see the left bottom corner of Eclipse click on the `+` sign and select `LogCat`

Comment: Actually I am able to see the logcat in the eclipse screen. I am trying to print all the logs related to my application on the screen. How can I display all the logs related to my application in my application's screen?

Comment: Hey Richa follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242765/show-log-messages-on-screen-for-android-application

Answer (score 0):

i hope your using eclipse, you can find it in ddms window.

Comment: How can we copy all the logs related to a particular application into a text file?

Comment: Select a log then press Ctrl+A then Ctrl+C and paste in txt file

Comment: @Richa some time err files are automatically copied to your project folder in workspace . have you noticed any .log file?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your project in Android Studio
2. From the **Analyze** menu, click **Analyze Stack Trace or Thread Dump**. [image: It looks like this]
3. Paste the stack trace text into the **Analyze Stack Trace** window and click **OK**.[image: Stack Trace Dialog]
4. Android Studio opens a new **Stacktrace** tab with the stack trace you pasted under the **Run** window.[image: StackTrace Tab]