# Android Emulator Can't bind to local 8601, 8600 for debugger

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I have a Mac with java version "1.8.0_191" when I run my android application it's working fine in the Emulator but when I start debugging the application it's not launching the app instead it's throwing me an error like below

```
 "Can't bind to local 8600 for debugger"
```

[image]

[image]

have tried below reference no luck
[DDMS - Can't bind to local 8600 for debugger on Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32507534/ddms-cant-bind-to-local-8600-for-debugger-on-android-studio/32507892#32507892)

could anyone please suggest me how to solve this problem

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried ```adb kill-server, adb start-server``` and to toggle USB Debugging on the emulated device?

Comment: Do you have something already running on 8600?

Comment: i tried like below its not worked for me.... cd /Users/varunagiri/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools adb kill-server -bash: adb: command not found

Comment: @IvanKaloyanov how to check which task is running on 8600?

Comment: @Vignesh lsof -i:8600/sudo lsof -i:8600. If something is running on the port try to kill it by PID: sudo kill <process PID> and try to start the debugger again.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, I tried with different emulator device and its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer for my question.

Android Studio 3.2.1 version **Tool -> SDK Version -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run**. Uncheck the **Enable Instant Run** and Click **Ok**.