# How to show current CPU load with Android Device Monitor?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to watch the current CPU load of an Android-app like with any activity monitor on MacOS or in the task manager of windows.

Apparently Android offers the Android Device Monitor for that.
Unfortunately this Device Monitor displays not the specific section for CPU load that is shown below in the picture from the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-basics.html#rearranging):

[image]

But i can't find neither the "Monitor" Tab in the Device Monitor window nor the "view"-Menu to activate it, which was mentioned in the documentation.

This is how it looks like on my development machine (Macbook with MacOS Sierra):

[image]

How can i enable the CPU- and memory graphs?

Android-Studio: 2.2.3
Android-SDK: 7.1 and 6.0

### Summary / TL;DR:

This question is not about how to open the Android Device Monitor. This question is aboput how to active the CPU-Load-View within the Android Device Monitor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio and android device monitor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29488165/android-studio-and-android-device-monitor)

Comment: Unfortuantely not. I've already found the Android Device Monitor as you can see in my personal screenshot. My Question goes one step ahead: how to display the CPU usage within the Android Device Monitor @nico

Answer (score 1):

> Apparently Android offers the Android Device Monitor for that (a picture from the official documentation):

That documentation and screenshot refers to the Android Monitor, which is not the same as the Android Device Monitor.

(sorry — I didn't name them)

> This is how it looks like on my development machine (Macbook with MacOS Sierra)

Step #1: Close that window, as it is irrelevant

Step #2: Return to the main Android Studio window

Step #3: Click on the "Android Monitor" tool, docked by default along the bottom edge of the IDE window

Step #4: Click on the "Monitors" tab in the Android Monitor tool window, which will now give you the output that you see in your first screenshot

Comment: Wow, that was pretty easy :) Thx!