# Logcat is not showing anything on android studio

Tags: android-studio, logcat

So I am using an emulator and logcat is empty, even my custom logs are not coming up, however if I navigate to the terminal in Android studio I can see that it's looking at my project folder instead of `android-sdk/platform-tools` where the `adb.exe` is.
When I use that terminal to navigate there and run `adb logcat` I can see the log fine.
Could that be the reason why the logcat is not working? And if it is how can I fix that?

I am also sure that I have logcat pointed to the correct device & project.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried restarting logcat? Like so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432358/android-studio-logcat-nothing-to-show

Comment: @MarkaA yep tried doing that, also restarted server, also restarted android studio and computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will help you at all, but it's something I ran into recently after upgrading to Android Studio 1.5 that took me hours to resolve.

Because I'm sharing common code between android and non-android, I wrote my own logging interface and more than one implementation.

In the android implementation, I used "" as a tag. This wasn't a problem before I upgraded to Android Studio 1.5, messages would show up as:

*I/ debugging message*

However, after upgrading to Android Studio 1.5, I could still see system log messages but all my own log messages were gone.

Finally it occurred to me that perhaps now an empty tag is no longer supported and sure enough, once I added in tags that were not empty strings my debugging messages returned.

Answer (score 1):

I recall that if you are in Windows some external scripts fail if your full path to adb.exe contains a space.  Make sure you have your adb in a directory that has no space.  For example:

This is my original adb location C:\Users\Mark A\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe

I transferred all my folder to a new folder with no spaces and recsynched everything to make it work.

Am not sure this is your issue but it may help others.

Good luck.

Comment: Nope, my adb is in: D:\AndroidSDK\platform-tools so I don't think that this would be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you already choose device and application to see log.
[image]

Comment: Yep I checked that and I am sure that I have the correct device and application.

Comment: Are you check Log Level, Filter also?

Comment: Yes, none of these are the reasons behind the issue