# Android Logcat is working on real device,but empty when debugging with EMULATOR in android studio 2.2.3?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-logcat, android-studio-2.2.3

When I try to debug using EMULATOR in android studio Logcat shows nothing. But when I use DEVICE, LogCat shows all the messages. How should view the Logcat messages when debugging on EMULATOR?

Comment: Try restarting adb or restart android studio

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android studio logcat nothing to show](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432358/android-studio-logcat-nothing-to-show)

Comment: yes you can check this [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432358/android-studio-logcat-nothing-to-show), it will help you out.