# ADB Logcat show nothing

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, adb

I'm having trouble with ADB Logcat.

What I did:
(in my android device, I'm using LG G6):

- turned USB debugging on
- connected the device to the computer

(in my computer)

- used windows powershell
- `cd AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools`

I did `.\adb devices` and the output is

`List of devices attached
LGH870DSe2cfa712        device`

I did `.\adb logcat -s Unity ActivityManager PackageManager dalvikvm DEBUG` and it showed nothing. It worked normally a few days ago.

when I disconnected the device, the adb automatically stopped the logcat.
I tried doing adb when no devices are connected and it showed 
`-waiting for devices-`, then I connected the device and nohthing happened.

I then tried another device (Asus Zenfone 3 max) and the powershell showed this:

```
PS C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools> .\adb logcat -s Unity ActivityManager PackageManager
dalvikvm DEBUG
--------- beginning of crash
--------- beginning of system
11-21 18:55:19.463  1025  3687 E ActivityManager: getContentProviderImpl: Update provider ProcessRecord{a16dbf1 1025:sys
tem/1000} conProviers's adj. conProviders.provider.proc=ProcessRecord{5a0c559 32615:com.android.providers.calendar/u0a20
} stableCount=1
11-21 19:53:41.976  1025  1123 E ActivityManager: getContentProviderImpl: Update provider ProcessRecord{ea76cc2 2487:com
.asus.contacts/u0a7} conProviers's adj. conProviders.provider.proc=ProcessRecord{deae782 4065:android.process.acore/u0a2
1} stableCount=1
11-21 19:53:42.181  1025  1862 E ActivityManager: getContentProviderImpl: Update provider ProcessRecord{ea76cc2 2487:com
.asus.contacts/u0a7} conProviers's adj. conProviders.provider.proc=ProcessRecord{deae782 4065:android.process.acore/u0a2
1} stableCount=1
11-21 19:53:42.182  1025  1862 E ActivityManager: getContentProviderImpl: Update provider ProcessRecord{ea76cc2 2487:com
.asus.contacts/u0a7} conProviers's adj. conProviders.provider.proc=ProcessRecord{deae782 4065:android.process.acore/u0a2
1} stableCount=1
11-21 19:53:42.438  1025  1036 E ActivityManager: getContentProviderImpl: Update provider ProcessRecord{ea76cc2 2487:com
.asus.contacts/u0a7} conProviers's adj. conProviders.provider.proc=ProcessRecord{deae782 4065:android.process.acore/u0a2
1} stableCount=1
11-21 19:53:42.441  1025  4847 E ActivityManager: getContentProviderImpl: Update provider ProcessRecord{ea76cc2 2487:com
.asus.contacts/u0a7} conProviers's adj. conProviders.provider.proc=ProcessRecord{deae782 4065:android.process.acore/u0a2
1} stableCount=1
11-21 19:53:59.530  1025  4846 E ActivityManager: getContentProviderImpl: Update provider ProcessRecord{ea76cc2 2487:com
.asus.contacts/u0a7} conProviers's adj. conProviders.provider.proc=ProcessRecord{deae782 4065:android.process.acore/u0a2
1} stableCount=1
11-21 19:53:59.714  1025  1036 E ActivityManager: getContentProviderImpl: Update provider ProcessRecord{ea76cc2 2487:com
.asus.contacts/u0a7} conProviers's adj. conProviders.provider.proc=ProcessRecord{deae782 4065:android.process.acore/u0a2
1} stableCount=1
11-21 19:53:59.717  1025  1854 E ActivityManager: getContentProviderImpl: Update provider ProcessRecord{ea76cc2 2487:com
.asus.contacts/u0a7} conProviers's adj. conProviders.provider.proc=ProcessRecord{deae782 4065:android.process.acore/u0a2
1} stableCount=1
11-22 05:51:02.514  1025  1880 E ActivityManager: getContentProviderImpl: Update provider ProcessRecord{676c3b4 17393:co
m.google.android.music:main/u0a93} conProviers's adj. conProviders.provider.proc=ProcessRecord{454972e 12856:android.pro
cess.media/u0a25} stableCount=1
11-22 08:59:19.897  1025  4918 E ActivityManager: getContentProviderImpl: Update provider ProcessRecord{2803ff2 23335:co
m.asus.appinstallationservice/u0a3} conProviers's adj. conProviders.provider.proc=ProcessRecord{4b76a2e 23347:com.asus.a
ppmanager/u0a48} stableCount=1
11-22 10:21:45.378  1025  4846 E ActivityManager: getContentProviderImpl: Update provider ProcessRecord{1c417d4 27927:co
m.google.android.music:main/u0a93} conProviers's adj. conProviders.provider.proc=ProcessRecord{92edd91 23964:android.pro
cess.media/u0a25} stableCount=1
11-22 14:08:13.447  1025  1860 E ActivityManager: Exception thrown starting services in ProcessRecord{9f1e55c 0:com.andr
oid.chrome:sandboxed_process0/u0a67i371}
11-22 14:08:13.447  1025  1860 E ActivityManager:       at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
11-22 14:08:13.447  1025  1860 E ActivityManager: android.os.DeadObjectException
11-22 14:08:13.447  1025  1860 E ActivityManager:       at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:511)
11-22 14:08:13.447  1025  1860 E ActivityManager:       at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.scheduleCreateService(Appl
icationThreadNative.java:980)
11-22 14:08:13.447  1025  1860 E ActivityManager:       at com.android.server.am.ActiveServices.realStartServiceLocked(A
ctiveServices.java:1675)
11-22 14:08:13.447  1025  1860 E ActivityManager:       at com.android.server.am.ActiveServices.attachApplicationLocked(
ActiveServices.java:2229)
11-22 14:08:13.447  1025  1860 E ActivityManager:       at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.attachApplicatio
nLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:6977)
11-22 14:08:13.447  1025  1860 E ActivityManager:       at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.attachApplicatio
n(ActivityManagerService.java:7033)
11-22 14:08:13.447  1025  1860 E ActivityManager:       at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerN
ative.java:513)
11-22 14:08:13.447  1025  1860 E ActivityManager:       at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(Activ
ityManagerService.java:2729)
11-22 14:08:13.447  1025  1860 E ActivityManager:       at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:458)
11-22 14:31:43.717  1025  1860 E ActivityManager: getContentProviderImpl: Update provider ProcessRecord{8d82dfe 5479:com
.google.android.music:main/u0a93} conProviers's adj. conProviders.provider.proc=ProcessRecord{630085 3520:android.proces
s.media/u0a25} stableCount=1

11-22 17:43:54.387  1025  4918 D ActivityManager: publishContentProviders: from caller=android.app.ApplicationThreadProx
y@a9b5ab0 (pid=12170)
```

I tried searching this and got no solution.
Please help.

Comment: I've had something (not exactly) similiar happen before, but in my case the authorization for ADB got corrupted. I fixed it by revoking all ADB authorizations. To do this you can go to developer options -> ADB debuggig -> Revoke all ADB authorizations. It may be worth a shot for your case aswel. After doing this you have to grant acces for ADB debugging when connecting to your pc again though.

Comment: @remy_rm just tried that and nothing happened

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432358/android-studio-logcat-nothing-to-show

Comment: @royatirek tried using `.\adb kill-server` then `.\adb start-server` nothing happened

Answer (score 5):

Here is something I noticed.

I have a couple of devices that shows nothing when I run `adb logcat`, but logcat works if I see the log in Android Studio. When that happens, I run `adb shell -t logcat`, which seems to work.

Comment: Works perfect with LG G6 Android 8, thank you @solamour

Answer (score 3):

What is you adb version and LG G6 version?

adb 1.0.39 work well with LG G6 (android7) if you need adb logcat .

adb 1.0.40 and 1.0.41 unable work with  LG G6 (android7) .

Comment: Thank you, that the only way I was able to fix this problem.