# Android Studio logcat not display exception after update

Tags: android-studio

Recently I was update Android Studio to 3.4 and the logcat no longer shows exception like Figure 2.

I have demonstrate the logcat with same error in Android Studio using two pc.
Figure 1 is the logcat that shows in the Android Studio 3.4 while Figure 2 is the logcat shows in Android Studio 3.3.2 in another pc.

Any idea on how to get back the logcat like Figure 2?

Figure 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/McE03.png

Figure 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fgx6H.png

Comment: Try File > Invalidate Caches/Restart

Comment: Not working. Also tried restart logcat and change to no filter.

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432358/android-studio-logcat-nothing-to-show) there is a similar problem.

Comment: @Legion Still not working

Comment: Problem solved. link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124334/huawei-logcat-not-showing-the-log-for-my-app. Never thought because of the phone problem because I able to debug using the same phone previously.