# Unable to click image view

Tags: android

I have image view in my activity and when I click over Image view it is not showing anything in Log cat neither in toast message.

This is my code below:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<ImageView
     android:layout_width="30dp"
     android:layout_height="30dp"
     android:src="@drawable/heart"
     android:id="@+id/heartButton"
     android:clickable="true"
     android:focusable="true"/>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
ImageView heartButton = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.heartButton);

heartButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           Log.d("Click","Hello");

        }
    });
```

Someone please let me know why this imageview click listener is not working.
Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Comment: You need to add complete code of your MainActivity. Whatever you've given right now looks correct to me

Comment: Add your layout code please

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432358/android-studio-logcat-nothing-to-show

Comment: post your full xml code

Comment: add complete code of your activity

Comment: Why don't you use an ImageButton?

Comment: @Luca, Yes now I have implemented ImageButton and its working fine.