# Ever since clearing logcat, logcat shows nothing

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

About a week ago I cleared logcat with the "clear logcat" button on the top left of the logcat screen. Since then, nothing shows up in logcat.

This may sound like some duplicate question, but I have tried every accepted answer with no change. I need some ideas or solutions. Don't close this saying it's a duplicate please.

I have invalidated caches/restarted.

Restarted Android Studio.

Restarted my phone.

Killed, Restarted, updated the adb.

Restarted computer.

Pressed alt+6 multiple times to restart logcat.

Hit the restart button in the logcat panel. Then changed options like debug/verbose as other solutions say.

I have also checked and rechecked every field in logcat (verbose, no filter, etc) and have tried every possible combination, including the usual "fix" of verbose + no filter. I can't even get logs (Log.i, eg) to show up.

Another solution was to go to Tools>Android>Enable ADB integration. This option no longer exists.

More info: Windows 10, newest version. Android Studio 3.4.2.

Edit: My question is DIFFERENT because NONE of those solutions have worked, as stated originally.

I have also now done a complete clean reinstall of Android Studio and still no working logcat.

**Edit 2**: So I guess this must be a bug of some kind? No solutions after weeks of trying everything. I'll contact Android support I guess? Hopefully it works out.

Comment: What do you mean "newest version" for Android Studio? There are beta and canary versions too...

Comment: on the right side of the logcat window, have you changed the dropdown between `No Filter` and `Show only selected applcation` ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody yes, I have tried every default logcat configuration, on the right with no filter, only selected, etc, as well as the left-center panel (verbose, error, etc).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android studio logcat nothing to show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432358/android-studio-logcat-nothing-to-show)

Comment: @SarthakJoshi I have tried every reply in that thread, and did so before making my own question.

Comment: Then re-install your  Android Studio @therealone.

Comment: @SarthakJoshi thanks, but I have three times so far. Twice being total clean installs (deleting anything and everything to do with AS on the computer, appdata stuff, etc)

Comment: I am asking you to Un-install your Android studio and Re-install it had you tried that.I am not saying to clean the project and re-build it. @therealone

Comment: @SarthakJoshi yes, I meant uninstalling and reinstalling Android Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My model of ZTE phone does not allow logcat. People have reported the same issue with this phone. So it's the phone and not Android Studio or my app.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding debuggable: "true" to the application tag in manifest. Compile your project now and you'll saw every log in the logcat. Hope it may help you.

Comment: Late reply, but it turns out my ZTE phone is notorious for not allowing logcat. Many people report the same with this phone.