# Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 1 doesn't show any logs(log.d or any) in the logcat

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-studio-girafee

I am using Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 1. I cannot see any logs with Log.d() or Log.v() in the logcat for my application with the filter 'package:mine' or even with the specific class name.
If I add those logs with the Println() command, I can see the same.

I tried these solutions:

1. Invalidate & Restart
2. Close logcat & start
3. Close device and restart

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android studio logcat nothing to show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432358/android-studio-logcat-nothing-to-show)

Comment: No, that doesn't work. some of them are for older Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also facing this issue many time when 2 apps running together and i'm getting one app's log in another one app.

```
1. Please clear your filter from logcat and try again.

2. Delete all log from old app.
```

Comment: so those steps solved the problem for you?