# Is it possible to access logs from another App?

Tags: android, logging, android-activity

I want to develop an App (let's call it B) that overlays another one (let's call it A), the App B perform some tasks dependind on what the user is doing in A. So my question is, any ideas on how can i read the logs from A without being root?
I have checked theese: [How to read android log cat programmatically for other applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22127349/how-to-read-android-log-cat-programmatically-for-other-applications)
[Show log messages on screen for Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242765/show-log-messages-on-screen-for-android-application)

But none of them works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This used to be possible in earlier versions of Android.

But it's no longer possible for nearly all still-used versions of Android.

See this post: [How to read android log cat programmatically for other applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22127349/how-to-read-android-log-cat-programmatically-for-other-applications)